# OpenOffice embedd in Java

Tags: java, java-native-interface, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I want to use an openoffice component (text/calc/...) in my Java program.  I tried [NOA](http://code.google.com/p/noa-libre/) on my Win7 64bit, JRE 1.7 (64bit) and openoffice 3.2. I got this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: J:\downloads\noa-libre-package-0.2.1\noa-libre-package-0.2.1\lib\nativeview.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
```

Can you somebody help me, please? I tried to find nativeview.dll for 64bit win (7), but not found.

Answer (score 0):

Try again with v 0.3, I believe it is not an issue at this point in time.  I see that there is a lib/64bit directory in this release.

I have that version plus Win7 64bit + JRE 1.7 (64 bit) + OO 3.4.1 (32-bit) + Eclipse Juno Release 2(64 bit).  I ran the Snippet10 in the examples folder provided with the release, which opens an existing open office text file, and everything worked for me.  OO opened to my sample file which I provided.